# How do I remove "set build.dir" error while running a project on NetBeans

Tags: java, web, web-applications, ide, netbeans-8

I import a project on NetBeans but while running it shows " set build.dir" I have go through all but it didn't fix.

Project files with `project.properties` open
[image: what I have to kept in build.dir]

Comment: You've opened a file called `project.properties.txt`, it is not the same as `project.properties` which is also present. Please set `build.dir` in `project.properties`. I would also try to add a `/` to the build.dir just in case; like so: `build.dir=build/`

Answer (score 0):

That error indicates that you haven't set the `build.dir` property.
There might be an easier way to set it now, but some years ago I did it "manually" by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> to open the `files` window.

Navigate to the project you're having problems with, open the folder `nbproject` and double click to open the `project.properties` file. Add the missing `build.dir` property by setting it to the desired directory (usually a path relative to where the project is located; `build.dir=build/` is probably the default value

Comment: I have added the image of my project file so what you think what I have to set my build.dir